# Issues loading Jquery on Wordpress website

Tags: jquery, javascript

Please assist, I am trying to load this Jquery on my Wordpress website with no luck.

I have used this script just BEFORE the `</body>` tag in my functions.php :

```
<script type="text/javascript"
   src="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/js/menu-hover.js"></script>
```

I have used this code in the  of my functions.php file:

```
<?php
if (!is_admin()) add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "my_jquery_enqueue", 11);
function my_jquery_enqueue() {
   wp_deregister_script('jquery');
   wp_register_script('jquery', "http" . ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? "s" : "") . "://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/js/jquery.min.js", false, null);
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
?>
```

This is my Jquery/Javascript code:

```
jQuery( "#panel-2-1-0-0" ).hover( //Print and Document
    function() {
        jQuery('#mega-menu-item-475').addClass('mega-toggle-on');
    }, function() {
        jQuery('#mega-menu-item-475').removeClass('mega-toggle-on');
    }
);

jQuery( "#panel-2-1-1-0" ).hover( //Telecom
    function() {
        jQuery('#mega-menu-item-477').addClass('mega-toggle-on');
    }, function() {
        jQuery('#mega-menu-item-477').removeClass('mega-toggle-on');
    }
);

jQuery( "#panel-2-1-0-1" ).hover( //IT Dev
    function() {
        jQuery('#mega-menu-item-476').addClass('mega-toggle-on');
    }, function() {
        jQuery('#mega-menu-item-476').removeClass('mega-toggle-on');
    }
);

jQuery( "#panel-2-1-1-1" ).hover( // Safety and Security
    function() {
        jQuery('#mega-menu-item-478').addClass('mega-toggle-on');
    }, function() {
        jQuery('#mega-menu-item-478').removeClass('mega-toggle-on');
    }
);
```

Comment: 1. Why are you loading another version of jQuery? The standard one should be able to do `.addClass` and `.removeClass` just fine. 2. Why are you trying to load the script via `<script>` tags and not `wp_enqueue_script` with a dependancy set?

Comment: Hi Kero, Im not sure if you can see the coding properly. I have tried using this code in my <head> as well :

Comment: add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script' );

function add_my_script() {
wp_enqueue_script(
    'your_script_name', // your script unique name 
    get_template_directory_uri().'/js/your-script.js', //script file location
    array('jquery') //lists the scripts upon which your script depends
);
}

Comment: I have tried the en queue function with no luck

Comment: function file is the best choice for enqueuing  styles and scripts. however if you willing to add javascript/jquery inside the head tag use as <script type="text/javascript"
   src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/menu-hover.js"></script>. if you are going to include using function file, @Bradley way is right.

Answer (score 1):

1. [Don't enqueue your own version of jQuery](https://pippinsplugins.com/why-loading-your-own-jquery-is-irresponsible/). You're just going to cause conflict issues with other plugins and there's nothing in your script that requires a different version.
2. Even if you were, [just load the https:// version](https://twitter.com/paul_irish/status/588502455530311680), there's no reason to bother checking what your own server is doing.
3. Don't bother checking `!is_admin()` on your enqueue function, `wp_enqueue_scripts` doesn't even run in admin.
4. Don't add script tags in templates, use `wp_enqueue_script()`.
5. The proper way, these days, to get the URL to a theme file is [`get_theme_file_uri()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_theme_file_uri/).
6. When you say "I have used this script just BEFORE the `</body>` tag in my functions.php :", you don't actually mean your `</body>` tag is in functions.php do you?

Put all together, your code should just be this, in your functions.php file:

```
function wpse_283386_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'menu-hover', get_theme_file_uri( 'js/menu-hover.js' ), array( 'jquery' ), '', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_283386_enqueue_scripts' );
```

The only reasons it wouldn't work after this are:

1. The IDs you're targeting in your script don't exist.
2. The classes you're adding and removing don't do anything in your CSS.
3. `/wp-content/themes/{your theme}/js/menu-hover.js` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

**This is the code I am using in the themes functions.php, exactly as advised:**

[image]

**This is the path where menu-hover.js exists:**

[image]